# Choose Xpath version for Saxonc Xpath processor

Tags: xpath, saxon-c

I just installed Saxonc Python API. All the examples work fine. However, every time I try to evaluate my own expressions, the XPath processor returns an empty sequence. I tested the expressions using Oxygen, and it works well and selects the right node under Xpath 2.0. I think the issue may be that by default, the Xpath processor uses Xpath version 1.0.

Saxonc Python API documentation says that:

> Saxon/C provides processing in XSLT 3.0, XQuery 3.0/3.1 and XPath 2.0/3.0/3.1, and Schema validation 1.0/1.1.

However, I can't find how to change the Xpath version.

Comment: Hi,the Saxon/C XPathProcessor object should work fine with XPath 2.0+. Please can you send me a repo.

Comment: Although the underlying engine has support for different versions of XPath, I don't think we actually expose that in the Python API, so the documentation is misleading. It should just be XPath 3.1. The C API has the option to set XPath 1.0 compatibility mode but I don't think that's in the documented Python API.